# Error in checkmvArgs(lower = lower, upper = upper, mean = delta, corr = corr, : ‘lower’ not specified or contains NA

Tags: r, database, data-analysis, anova

I am trying to use R to conduct pairwise comparisons while controlling the experiment-wise error rate at α = 0.05. I need the values Estimate, SE, and Test. Below is my code I am trying to run and the data for the program.

```
library(multcomp)
data6$Treatment <- factor(data6$Treatment)
m1 <- aov(Sample.mean ~ Treatment, data6)
result <- glht(m1, mcp(Treatment = "Tukey"))
summary(result)
```

Treatment  Sample.size  Sample.mean  Sample.variance

Herbicide_1 30             87.606   35.341
Herbicide_2 30             88.792   36.316
Control     40             84.095   36.592

Comment: would be great if you don't include data as image and share a minimal reproducable example. the error message suggests that there may be a problem with the arguments you provided for the glht() function. Specifically, it seems that the lower bound for the simultaneous confidence intervals is not specified or contains missing values...

Comment: @EirikFesker Sorry I am new to stack so I didn't realize. I would prefer if there was not any attitude going forward in your comments as I am just reaching out to people for help. Not snarky comments. I will update it now, could you please not dislike my post if you were the one who did that. As I am just trying to get help with R as I am learning. Also your comment is reiterating the error statement which does not really help at all. If you could please elaborate what the error message means.

Comment: Treatment  Sample.size    Sample.mean   Sample.variance
Herbicide 1 30                  87.606 35.341 
Herbicide 2 30                  88.792 36.316 
Control         40                  84.095 36.592